# Haskell lexical layout rule implementation

Tags: haskell, ghc, lexer

I have been working on a pet language, which has Haskell-like syntax. One of the neat things which Haskell does, which I have been trying to replicate, is its insertion of {, } and ; tokens based on code layout, before the parsing step.

I found http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html, which includes a specification of how to implement the layout program, and have made a version of it (modified, of course, for my (much simpler) language).

Unfortunately, I am getting an incorrect output for the following:

`f (do x y z) a b`

It should be producing the token stream `ID ( DO { ID ID ID } ) ID ID`, but it is instead producing the token stream `ID ( DO { ID ID ID ) ID ID }`.

I imagine that this is due to my unsatisfactory implementation of `parse-error(t)` (`parse-error(t) = false`), but I have no idea how I would go about implementing `parse-error(t)` efficiently.

How do Haskell compilers like GHC etc. handle this case? Is there an easy way to implement `parse-error(t)` such that it handles this case (and hopefully others that I haven't noticed yet)?

Comment: I don’t know how e.g. GHC implements it, but the way I’d implement it is to have the parser, after it consumes a `DO`, see if there’s a `{`, and if there is, expect it to end with a `}`; otherwise, stop parsing the contents of the block when the start column of a token that would potentially start a new item in the block is to the left of the start-column of the first one.

Comment: It's tricky to implement, and almost impossible to implement correctly for Haskell.  What are you using to implement your parser?

Comment: @augustss My parser is being implemented in Javascript. I don't have a full parser implemented yet, just a pencil/paper BNF grammar, and the lexer/layout code.

I was planning on using Jison (http://jison.org) to do the parsing.

My language is much more simple than Haskell, so I might not need a fully correct implementation of `parse-error(t)`, it just needs to handle some basic cases.

@icktoofay I am currently doing the parsing in 3 steps, lexing, layout, and then parsing. The layout algorithm is doing basically that, but it doesn't have enough context to handle do blocks in brackets.

Comment: If Jison is like YACC/Bison then you can use an error production to insert the right curly.

Comment: @augustss I took a look at some of the code [generated](http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/) by jison, and it definitely has an error production, but I don't see the any code which will ever use it. Errors seem to be fed into an error reporting function, and there doesn't seem to be a way for the parser to recover once an error has occurred. I'll look into it more when I get home.

Comment: @Mystor In YACC/Bison you have to put 'error' in the grammar to get a production to match an error.

Comment: GHC implements the offside rule in the lexer https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Lexer.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom version of the parsing algorithm used by JISON's compiled parsers, which takes an immutable state object, and a token, and performs as much work as possible with the token before returning. I am then able to use this implementation to check if a token will produce a parse error, and easily roll back to previous states of the parser.

It works fairly well, although it is a bit of a hack right now. You can find the code here: https://github.com/mystor/myst/blob/cb9b7b7d83e5d00f45bef0f994e3a4ce71c11bee/compiler/layout.js

I tried doing what @augustss suggested, using the error production to fake the token's insertion, but it appears as though JISON doesn't have all of the tools which I need in order to get a reliable implementation, and re-implementing a stripped-down version of the parsing algorithm turned out to be easier, and lined up better with the original document.