# How do Haskell compilers implement the parse-error(t) rule in practice?

Tags: parsing, haskell, ghc, lexical-analysis

The Haskell Report includes a somewhat notorious clause in the layout rules called "[parse-error(t)](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3)". The purpose of this rule is to avoid forcing the programmer to write braces in single-line `let` expressions and similar situations. The relevant sentence is:

> The side condition parse-error(t) is to be interpreted as follows: if the tokens generated so far by L together with the next token t represent an invalid prefix of the Haskell grammar, and the tokens generated so far by L followed by the token “}” represent a valid prefix of the Haskell grammar, then parse-error(t) is true.

This creates an unusual dependency where the lexer necessarily both produces tokens for the parser and responds to errors produced in the parser by inserting additional tokens for the parser to consume. This is unlike pretty much anything you'll find in any other language definition, and severely complicates the implementation if it is interpreted 100% literally.

Unsurprisingly, no Haskell compiler that I'm aware of implements the entire rule as written. For example, [GHC fails to parse the following expression](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs-and-infelicities.html#infelicities-syntax), which is legal according to the report:

```
let x = 42 in x == 42 == True
```

There are a wide variety of other similar strange cases. [This post](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/mail-www/haskell/msg01711.html) has a list of some especially difficult examples. Some of these GHC works correctly on, but it also (as of 7.10.1) fails on this one:

```
e = case 1 of 1 -> 1 :: Int + 1
```

Also, it seems GHC has an undocumented language extension called [`AlternativeLayoutRule`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/AlternativeLayoutRule) that replaces the parse-error(t) clause with a stack of token contexts in the lexer that gives similar results in most cases; however, this is not the default behavior.

**What do real-world Haskell compilers (including GHC in particular) do to approximate the parse-error(t) rule during lexing?** I'm curious because I'm trying to implement a simple Haskell compiler and this rule is really tripping me up. (See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354942/haskell-lexical-layout-rule-implementation).)

Comment: Those strange cases you show were abolished in Haskell 2010 precisely because they are unreasonable to implement. Note how that post is from 1999.

Comment: Actually now I'm not sure about the second example. It seems to trip up GHC not because it doesn't handle parse-error, but because there's a syntax extension that makes `+` legal inside a type...

Comment: To see that GHC actually *tries* to implement the rule faithfully, note that `case 1 of 1 -> 1 :: Int :: Int` parses perfectly.

Comment: Seems that GHC at least implements the offside rule in the _lexer_ https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/parser/Lexer.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the `parse-error(t)` rule is *meant* to be hard to implement. Yes, it does require the parser to communicate back to the lexer, but other than that it was probably designed to be relatively *easy* to implement with the dominant parsing technology of the time: A LALR(1) based generated parser with some small support for error correction, like GNU Bison, or indeed like Happy, which GHC uses.

It might be ironic that, at least partially due to Haskell's success at enabling parser combinator libraries, that old technology is not as dominant as it used to be, at least in the Haskell community.

A LALR(1) (or LR(1)) generated parser has the following features that fit rather well with how the `parse-error(t)` rule is *intended* to be interpreted:

- It never backtracks.
- Its table-driven decisions mean that it always "knows" whether a given token is legal in the current spot, and if so, what to do with it.

Happy has a special `error` token that can be used to achieve actions when the current lexical token is *not* legal. Given this, the [most relevant definition](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/parser/Parser.y#L2796) in GHC's Happy grammar is

```
close :: { () } 
        : vccurly               { () } -- context popped in lexer. 
        | error                 {% popContext }
```

`vccurly` ("virtual close curly") is the token the lexer sends when it chooses by itself to close a layout level. `popContext` is [an action defined in the lexer source](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/parser/Lexer.x#L2157) that removes a layout level from the layout stack. (Note BTW that in this implementation, the `error` case does *not* need the lexer to send a `vccurly` token back).

Using this, all the GHC parser rules have to otherwise is to use `close` as their nonterminal token for ending an indentation block opened with `vocurly`. Assuming the rest of the grammar is correct, this implements the rule correctly too.

Or at least, that's the theory. It turns out that this sometimes breaks because of other features of Haskell/GHC that *don't* fit as well into LALR(1) grammar.

Of your two examples above, the first was changed in Haskell 2010 (because people realized it was too awkward to parse), so GHC is correct there. But the second (`e = case 1 of 1 -> 1 :: Int + 1`) happens because of a [different design decision](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/Parser) GHC makes:

> Making a parser parse precisely the right language is hard. So GHC's parser follows the following principle:
>
> - We often parse "over-generously", and filter out the bad cases later.

GHC has sufficient extensions that `Int + 1` *could* parse as a type with enough of them enabled.  Also, having to write a LALR(1)-parser to directly handle every combination of enabled/disabled extensions would be *really* awkward (not sure it's even possible). So it just parses the most general language first, and fails later when it checks if the needed extensions for the result are enabled.  But by that time parsing is finished and it's too late to trigger the `parse-error` rule. (Or so I'm assuming.)

Finally, I should say that I don't think there's anything *impossible* about handling the `parse-error(t)` rule even if you're not using a (LA)LR(1) parser. I suspect something like GHC's `close` token could work well in a combinator one too. But you still need some kind of communication back to the lexer.

Comment: I guess you could use parser combinators with a free monad and then compile that grammar down to a table driven parser... ^_^

Comment: @AaronRotenberg I think it is a "well-known" issue that if you want a parser to be analyzable enough to turn it into a table or the like, you need to use `Applicative` or `Arrow` composition instead of `Monad`. The `Monad` ability to make effects depend on arbitrary functions of the previous results ruins a lot of analysis.

Comment: I actually already knew that, I just didn't think about it when I made the comment. Replace "monad" with `Alternative` and it makes sense.